# how to recognize view elements from controller in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a view file in my MVC of Extjs where i have a radarChart so now i want to call two  fields i.e xaxis and yaxis of radarChart in the controller.here is my code

```
Ext.define('Gamma.view.RadarChart', {
extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
alias : 'widget.radarChart',
id:'radarChart',


margin: '0 0 0 0',
insetPadding: 40,
flex: 1.2,
animate: true,
store: 'RadarView',
theme: 'Yellow',
axes: [{
    steps: 4,
    type: 'Radial',
    position: 'radial',
    maximum: 60
}],
series: [{
    type: 'radar',
    xField: 'Name',
    yField: 'Data',
    showInLegend: false,
    showMarkers: true,
    markerConfig: {
        radius: 4,
        size: 4,
        fill: 'rgb(212, 40, 40)'
    },


    //        listeners:{
    //            itemmousedown : function(obj) {
    //                alert(obj.storeItem.data['Name']+ ' &' + obj.storeItem.data['Data']);
    //            }
    //        },
    style: {
        fill: 'rgb(94, 114, 13)',
        opacity: 0.5,
        'stroke-width': 0.5
    }
}]
});
```

anyone please help

Comment: i want to call these xField and yField in my controller

Comment: Can you show us your controller code? You just want to access those string values from your controller?